# Backup cpanel account with SSL

Tags: ssl, cpanel

I have a live server which has cPanel installed on it. It is hosting a website with a SSL certificate that got installed in Cpanel for the cpanel-user hosting the domain.

I now downloaded a backup of this cpanel account to my dev server (and restored it in WHM, dev server is using cpanel too) for testing purposes, however I have a question regarding the SSL:

Does the SSL certificate get copied when the cpanel account gets backed-up?

After changing my host file i am still able to see the website using SSL (even though its on the dev server and there was not a certificate installed). My understanding was that the SSL is specific for each server, because the CSR is done on the server the certificate should run on.

Why am I able to access both live and dev using https?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, SSL certificate will be migrate When you migrate OR restore your account through cPanel/WHM tool.

Comment: how does this work then, do i have basically two certificates then? I thought a certificate is specific for the server